# Enable compression for HTTP2 server-pushes on an apache server

Tags: apache-2.4, http, gzip, http2

If I enable H2 for my apache server and specify a preloaded link header on a HTML Dokument, the server performs a [H2 server-push](https://www.w3.org/TR/preload/) because it [parses the Link header](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/http2.html#push) -- so far so good.

The problem is that this pushed resource is delivered without compression.
I guess that's because a server-push doesn't create a HTTP request and therefore the `accept-encoding` request header is not provided.
The thing is, I don't get any performance improvements if the client has to download the uncompressed content.
Is it still possible to serve the content compressed? Maybe based on the `accept-encoding` request header from the HTML document?

**My apache config**:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    Protocols h2 http/1.1
    [...]
    <Location /index.html>
        Header add Link "</css/all.min.css>;rel=preload;as=style"
    </Location>
    [...]
</VirtualHost>
```

**The HTML Headers**:

Request headers from the HTML document

```
accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
accept-language:de,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
cache-control:no-cache
```

Response headers from the HTML document

```
accept-ranges:bytes
cache-control:no-transform,public,max-age=300,s-maxage=900
content-encoding:gzip
content-length:2183
content-type:text/html
etag:"2472-5385af4b7bbda-gzip"
last-modified:Sun, 24 Jul 2016 05:29:47 GMT
link:</css/all.min.css>;rel=preload;as=style
server:Apache/2.4.18 (Debian)
status:200
vary:Accept-Encoding
```

Response headers from /css/all.min.css

```
accept-ranges:bytes
cache-control:no-transform,public,max-age=300,s-maxage=900
content-length:14237
content-type:text/css
etag:"379d-5385af4b9139b"
last-modified:Sun, 24 Jul 2016 05:29:47 GMT
server:Apache/2.4.18 (Debian)
status:200
vary:Accept-Encoding
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like this is simply a bug in `mod_http2`, but it was fixed with version 1.2.6:
https://github.com/icing/mod_h2/issues/86

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use mod_deflate:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_deflate.html#enable

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you explained *why* you think mod_deflate should be used.

Comment: It is not like compression wouldn't work at all, it just doesn't works for resources delivered with a server-push.